# HP-LaserJet-100-colorMFP-M175a ppd file

Tags: printing, hp

I am trying to install hp printer HP-LaserJet-100-colorMFP-M175a  model and i can't seem to get it right.Where can i find the ppd file for this model?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from the HPLIP website:

> This printer REQUIRES a downloadable driver plug-in. Use hp-setup to install the printer, and to download and install the plug-in. In general, required driver plugins are required for printing support. Driver plug-ins are released under a proprietary (non-open) license and are not part of the HPLIP tarball release.
>   Blockquote

That means you have to download and install a proprietary Plugin from HP. Fortunately there is a tool that makes this easy.
Press alt+F2 and type in hp-setup, then press Enter. That is a tool that you can use to install that printer.

If you get "failed to install plugin" try typing "gksudo hp-setup" instead.

You can find more info about your printer here: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/color_laserjet/hp_laserjet_100_colormfp_m175b.html